# Bubbled event in StencilJs does not have correct event.target

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I started with Stencil some time ago and today I did an experiment with event bubbling.

Basically, I clicked on a child element and listened on its parent for `mousedown`. What I expected was that `event.target` to be my child component. This is super simple, for example if I run this test with regular DOM elements (not Stencil) it all works as expected

[image]

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tL3ugdzp/2/)

But in Stencil `event.target` is the parent element. Here is what I did. My parent component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    tag: 'app-root',
    styleUrl: 'app-root.scss',
    shadow: true 
})
export class MyApp {
    @Listen('mousedown')
    onMousedown(event) {
         console.log(event.target, event.currentTarget);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <my-element></my-element>
           </div> );
   }
}
```

And the child

```
@Component({
    tag: 'my-element',
    styleUrl: './my-element.scss',
    shadow: true
})
export class MyElement {
    @Listen('mousedown')
    onMouseDonw(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
    }

    render() {
       return ( <div>YO</div> );
    }
}
```

Now, as I said, when I click `my-element`, I first see the `console.log` from `my-element`, which confirms that `event.target` is `my-element`. But then the event arrives at its parent and `event.target` (but also `event.currentTarget`) contains `app-root`.  I noticed that when I set `shadow` to `false` of my `app-root` it all seems to work, but I don't understand why, and is this the only solution to my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's considered a feature of the encapsulation of the Shadow DOM. The original target is hidden as "internal implementation", and instead the event is re-targeted to the host element.

When you attach the listener with the `Listen` decorator within `MyApp`, it gets attached to the component's host element, which is `app-root` in this case.

You can use [`event.composedPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) to get the real target though (not supported in IE and old Edge).

Or you can catch the event from within the component and re-emit it as a custom event and forward the real event or target element:

```
export class MyApp {
    @Event() myMousedown: EventEmitter<MouseEvent>;

    handleElementMousedown = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        this.myMousedown.emit(event);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <my-element onMousedown={handleElementMousedown} />
           </div> );
   }
}
```

```js
document
    .querySelector('app-root')
    .attachEventListener('my-mousedown', console.log);
```

*(disclaimer: this code was not tested)*

Comment: This does not seem right. The event should be getting re-targeted to his custom element, "my-element". In no way should it be re-targeted to app-root for the listener he created in app-root. The re-targeting is meant to keep event.target from being some internal element inside of the custom element.

Comment: I think it has to do with where or when Listen attaches its listener. I tried this scenario but instead manually put a listener on the `div` in his `app-root`. Then the event target is correctly pointed at the my-element component. I think because app-root is itself a shadow component, the handler attached with Listen seems to be attached outside the component (on the host) and has already been re-targetted. Which makes Listen truly hard to use.

Comment: Ignore my previous (deleted) comments, I didn't look at the code in question properly. Let me rephrase it: `app-root` has shadow DOM enabled, which means that it will be event target for `click`/`mousedown`/etc events, no matter what exactly is clicked inside `app-root`. It doesn't matter that there's a nested custom element (`my-element`).

Comment: Regarding what you said about adding a listener on the `div`: now you are inside the shadow DOM, and yes, the event will bubble correctly within the shadow DOM. It just won't cross the shadow DOM border (i. e. the host). That's why I said you can catch the event that bubbles within the component and re-emit it as a custom event. I don't have time now to provide an example though, sorry. But basically it could be like what you did: attaching a listener to the `div` and then emitting an event from the host.

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion I came to. I think the confusion is caused by the `@Listen` annotation. I think it's not a useful behavior to have `@Listen` only listening to events from the view of outside the shadow since it's only used within the implementation of a web component. So mostly, I'm just saying I think the crux of the question is why doesn't `@Listen` do what a user expects? I don't think the answer is that it's a feature of shadow DOM, it's a poor design choice in Stencil to put the event listener outside the shadow.

Comment: This is not a poor design choice, it's just the way things are. Using the `@Listen` decorator is the same thing as manually attaching a listener to the host element, e. g., you could do the same thing in the render method with `<Host onMouseDown={handler}>`, or with `document.querySelector('app-root').attachEventListener(handler)`. It would be way more confusing and unexpected behavior if Stencil created a wrapping element inside the component to attach the listener to, just so that it could catch events from inside the shadow DOM.

Comment: So in the end the answer is: it's a design choice in the web components spec about how event listeners work on shadow DOM hosts, and whether that's a poor choice is up for discussion, but it's not a poor design choice in Stencil to follow the spec.

Comment: "The way things are" is a design choice. Nevertheless, I think what would clarify the answer and help people understand is if you emphasized that this happens because the listener is attached to the host element, so it sees the event from outside the shadow. Stencil docs don't say where it gets attached and it's counter intuitive that you can't get the correct target from `target`. Where you say "The original target is hidden as 'internal implementation'", any dev would consider the component's methods to be part of "internal implementation".

Comment: "The way things are" was referring to the web components standard (which yeah of course there was a design choice there), i. e., it's nothing that Stencil can change now. Like you would blame Sass that vertical padding is relative to an element’s width not height. I can agree that this behavior is quirky and confusing, but I disagree with downvoting a technically correct answer because one didn't understand it. Anyway, I'll add some clarification.